# Android users which download app

Tags: android

Is there any way of getting to know who has bought your app on the Android Market? I currently haven't got an account on the market, my app is still in development so i'm asking you guys.

I'd like to know and make a list of the people who purchased, or downloaded for free, my apps. Not their email addresses or anything, just some unique usernames, maybe from the Android Market itself. Is that possible?

If not, is there any way to get this information AFTER the app has been bought? The in-app billing system i'm guessing is anonymous as well, as it's still part of the Google/Android Market billing system. But if i were to use PayPal to make "my own in-app billing" would that work? I'm guessing i can see any PayPal transactions from where/who it originated, no?

If someone can offer me a suggestion on how i could get this information, with the user's willing participation of course, i'd be grateful.

Comment: I wish you could, it would help me when people give me one star ratings without explaining the problem they had :D But unfortunately I think that data is all hidden away.

Comment: I have no experience using paypal, but I'm sure that would work. I offered a more integrated solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To track users, people generally use some kind of Analytics app: 
[Google Analytics for Android](https://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/overview.html) and [Flurry](http://dev.flurry.com) are popular, to name a couple.

I know of no other way to track general downloads, other than the [Android developer dashboard/console](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-market-developer-console-adds-new-metrics-its-application-statistics)

To answer your first question:

Google Android purchases (market and in-app) [show up in the Merchant section of Google Checkout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/merchant-sales-reports-on-android.html).

EDIT: Also, once a purchase is made, it is not anonymous and you as a merchant have freedom to contact the customer directly.

EDIT #2: To address your second comment:

From https://checkout.google.com/sell/orders a merchant can see the following information for each order:

- Google Checkout Order Number
- Total $ (or other currency) Amount
- If they've yet been charged/pending/or other Credit Card/Other processing problems and current status.
- Order Details (Include user name - which is Full Name - and App Name)

Additionally, within each order you get:

- Customer's full name
- Billing Address
- Full email, not masked
- Sold on, Charged on, Confirmed on Dates/Times
- App name ID

So, Quite a bit information.

Comment: Wait. So you are telling me that if i post my app on the market for a small fee, i can contact every user which buys my app? Do i get a list of, let's say, 10k elements (if my app was downloaded 10k times) which contains every user who downloaded it? I'm confused, i asked a couple of people and they all said you can't, you can only see the number of people which downloaded it, but can't contact each and every one of them individually. Or were they referring only to the comments section? Hmm.
I'm sorry for the repetition but i'm confused and excited at the same time.

Comment: Just looked at the 3rd link you provided and it seems that you are right. But in that specific example you can't see any user information, like email or a username. Is that included in the report but they just didn't display it on that site?

Comment: Right, you can only directly contact those who have used a payment method. But, you can track everyone. I basically answered two questions: _how can you track people_ (Dev. Dashboard, Analytics libraries, etc) and _who can you contact_ those who made a purchase of some kind.

Comment: Omg, you have no idea how happy i am right now that this is possible :D Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll add additional information to my solution to address your second comment.

Comment: Glad that was decent enough information, I was going to add screenshots, but thought that would take too long. Mahalo and good luck in your ventures as a dev ;-)